# IntelliJ RunClient 実行時のエラー

Tags: java, intellij-idea

プログラミング初心者です。
JAVA の勉強がてらマインクラフト JAVA 向けの mod をつくってみようと思い、
以下のサイトを参考に JDK などのインストールからやってみているのですが、
"Minecraft の起動" にて RunClient の実行中に下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

少し前に VisualStudio でC#を触ったことがあるくらいで、
JAVA の IntelliJ の勝手がわからず全くエラーの内容がわかりません。

このエラーを解消して参考サイトに記載の通りマインクラフトを起動できるようにしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

以下該当エラーコード

```
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\user\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_282\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

参考にしているサイト

[Minecraft 1.12.2 Forge Modの作成 その1 【開発環境の準備 IntelliJ IDEA】 | プロジェクトの作成 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Hiroya_W/items/7ad9bad0387ef3688d1e#%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

---

**追記1**

以下、 kunif 様のご提案で1.14.4にトライしてみた様子です。

まず https://qiita.com/Hiroya_W/items/f38089724d9358d1668d の実行構成を作成の項で記載の通り

```
PS C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\biwako_mod> .\gradlew genIntellijRuns
```

と打ち込みましたが、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Get-Process : 引数 '.\gradlew' を受け入れる位置指定パラメーターが見つかりません。 発生場所 行:1 文字:1 + PS C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\biwako_mod> .\gradlew　genIntellijRuns + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process]、ParameterBindingExcepti on + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands. GetProcessCommand –
```

---

**追記2**

https://www.tntmodders.com/tutorial/env-1144/
の通りに 1.14.4 環境でトライしてみました。
しかし、Forge の項 10 で実行構成選択の候補欄に "runClient" が見当たりませんでした。

その後、"構成と編集"で名前とタスクの欄に手書きで"runClient"と記入して実行したところ、
以下のエラーがでました。

```
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\user\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_282\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

---

**追記3**

mdk の zip ファイルを解凍したファイルを開く方法ではなく、
あらかじめ解凍したフォルダのなかから

- build.gradle
- gradlew.bat
- gradlew
- gradleフォルダ

を取り出してプロジェクトフォルダへ移し、それを開いて実行すると追記2での
実行構成選択欄に"runClient"がないという事態は収まりましたが、
そのまま実行すると

```
'runClient' の実行中にエラーが発生しました: '1.8' is misconfigured
```

というシンプルなエラーが出て失敗してしまいます。

---

**追記4**
回答いただいた通り実行すると、

```
[LWJGL] GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE error
     (空白)     
Exception in thread "main"
```

というエラーコードと、数行にわたる緑色のログを挟んで

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

という文が表れてマインクラフトは起動しないまま動作が止まってしまいました。

Comment: 使っているツール等の版数に依存してやり方がチョコチョコ変わるようですが。同じ人の記事や、割と最近と思われる記事など。[Minecraft 1.14.4 Forge Modの作成 その1 【開発環境の準備 IntelliJ IDEA】](https://qiita.com/Hiroya_W/items/f38089724d9358d1668d), [環境構築 (1.14.4)](https://www.tntmodders.com/tutorial/env-1144/), [Getting Started with Forge](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/)

Comment: 一応マインクラフトバージョン1.12.2で開発してみようと考えていたのですが...1.14.4でもトライしてみます。

Answer (score 1):

取り敢えず以下の記事を参考にして出来ているようです。
[環境構築 (1.14.4)](https://www.tntmodders.com/tutorial/env-1144/)

ただし少し手順を変えて以下のようにしています。

- OpenJDKはIntelliJ IDEA Community Edition からインストールするのではなく、別途ダウンロードして先にインストールしておきます。

  - [Prebuilt OpenJDK Binaries for Free!](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot)からOpenJDK 8 (LTS)のHotSpotを選択してダウンロード・インストール
  - その際には[AdoptOpenJDKのダウンロード及びインストール](https://www.javadrive.jp/start/install/index6.html)を参考に「Set JAVA_HOME variable」を有効にしてインストールします
- IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition はリリース版で最新の 2020.3.2を使いました。

  - [スタンドアロンインストール](https://pleiades.io/help/idea/installation-guide.html#standalone)時のオプションで32bit関連オプション以外は以下のように全てチェックを入れています。

    - 64-bit launcher
    - Add launchars dir to PATH
    - Add *Open Folder as Project*
    - Create Associations の拡張子4つ全て
- [Forge](https://files.minecraftforge.net/)のFilesからは、最新の 1.16.5 の Download Latest の mdk を使いました。

  - .zipファイルはC:\Develop\forge-1.16.5-36.0.10-mdkに展開しました
- IntelliJ IDEAで展開したプロジェクトのフォルダを指定してOpenすると、初回は環境設定のダウンロード等で20分程度時間がかかります。

  - 上記「環境構築 (1.14.4)」の「Forge」の 5. から 11. の手順で(ダウンロード中のログの一部に文字化けが発生しているように見える以外は)問題無く動作しています。
- ちなみに`forge-1.16.4-35.1.4-mdk`とか`forge-1.14.4-28.2.0-mdk`だと`runClient`でゲームの画面は出て音とか表示は行われますが、IntelliJ IDEAのログ表示部分に`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://myurl.me/`のエラーが表示されます。

---

上記からすると、環境変数の`JAVA_HOME`か`PATH`の設定有無や内容あたりが影響している可能性があります。
調べるか試してみるかしてみてください。

---

**追記4に関して**

そのエラーメッセージは、OpenGLのAPIが無効であるという物でしょう。
本当にOpenGLが無いのは考えにくいので、版数が古いとか、何かミスマッチがあるとかでしょうか。

検索するとこの辺が見つかりますが、これらにヒントがあるかは不明です。
[[1.15.2] GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE error (intellij)](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/86274-1152-glfw_api_unavailable-error-intellij/)
[Can't open a window in netbeans with LWJGL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46635283/9014308)
[some minecraft installs not working under windows 10 #119](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/119)
[LWJGL 3 does not detect OpenGL](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6296.0)
[LWJGL won't work outside NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33502482/9014308)

言わずもがなですが、以下のようなことでドライバ等を最新に更新したか確認してみてください。

- Windows UpdateでOS/デバイスドライバ/アプリケーション等が全て最新に更新されているか
- PCのベンダーが提供しているBIOS/ファームウェア/デバイスドライバの更新が全て適用されているか
- CPUがIntelならば、[インテル® ドライバー & サポート・アシスタント](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ja/download/28425/-) でインテル関連ドライバが全て更新されているか
- GPUがNVidia/AMDならば、それぞれのデバイスドライバが最新のものに更新されているか
- Javaのランタイム環境が複数インストールされていないか(複数あったら、今回使う1つだけ残してあとはアンインストールしてみる＆使うランタイムは修復インストールとか再インストールしてみる)

Comment: 追記をしました。